Additional ASP.NET Core Web APIs are not getting published to Docker production
I need some help regarding publishing the ASP.NET Core Web APIs to the gitlab docker production environment. I have inherited the code from another team, and the current APIs are working fine on production, even if I make changes on them and re-publish it again.
However, when I add another controller, it works well in the local environment, but fails to load in the production environment.
I have set the following in launchsettings.json:
  "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
  }

I added a default out-of-the-box controller and it works locally, but I get an http 404 error in the production environment.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace testweb.default
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file
variables:
  DOCKER_IMAGE_PRODUCTION : $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE 
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TEST       : $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE 
  DOCKER_IMAGE_DEV        : $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

stages :
  - push_registry_dev
  - update_manifests_dev
  - push_registry_test
  - update_manifests_test
  - push_registry_uat
  - update_manifests_uat

  
build_image_dev:
  stage: push_registry_dev
  image : mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
  services:
    - docker:24.0.6-dind
  variables: 
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - cat /etc/os-release
    - curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
    - echo -n $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    - dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
  script:
    # - cat .env.development > .env
    # - docker build  -f dev.Dockerfile --tag $DOCKER_IMAGE_TEST:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA-dev .
    #- dotnet ef database update --project TestProject.Infrastructure/ --startup-project TestProject.Web/ --connection "Server=***.***.***.***;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=sa;Password=*******;TrustServerCertificate=true"
    - cd ./TestProject.Web
    - dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 -p:PublishProfile=DefaultContainer -p:ContainerImageName=test-backend
    - docker tag test-backend $DOCKER_IMAGE_TEST:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA-dev
    - docker push $DOCKER_IMAGE_TEST:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA-dev

  only:
    - develop
    - main
    - prod
  tags :
    - gitlab-org-docker
 


update_manifest_dev:
  stage: update_manifests_dev
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  retry: 2
  image: docker:24.0.6
  services:
    - docker:24.0.6-dind
  script:
    # Add SSH key to root
    - mkdir -p /root/.ssh
    - cat "${GIT_SSH}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - apk add --no-cache git 
    - export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    - git config --global user.name "username"
    - git config --global user.email "email@gmail.com"
    - git clone --single-branch --branch main git@gitlab.com:company/k8s-manifests.git
    - cd k8s-manifests/test/dev/api
    - export REPO=$DOCKER_IMAGE_DEV:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA-dev
    - chmod -R 777 ${PWD}
    - docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/workdir -e REPO=$REPO mikefarah/yq:4.12.2  e '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image=env(REPO)' --inplace deployment.yml
    - git commit -am "New version updated ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}-dev" && git push origin main
  tags: 
    - gitlab-org-docker
  needs: ["build_image_dev"]
  only:
    refs:
    - develop
    - main
    - prod

Is there anything else I need to change in the code? I am not that conversant with docker technologies.

launchsettings.json is an IDE file so anything in there is only used when you launch your program from VS or Rider or whatever you use. It's not used when it's run in a container. I don't think that's your issue though. But something to be aware of.

Hi  Noorul, please try to run the application via the docker command, like docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production -p 8080:80 test-backend. Han Kilian's comment is useful, you can verify it by using my command.
